# Solving ODE for x instead of y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Find the general solution of the ODE. Give the largest interval over which the general solution is defined. Determine any transient terms in the general solution.

$y dx - 4(x+y^6)dy = 0$

This is non linear in terms of y but the answer key gives a solution in terms of x.

So I rewrote the function to
$\frac{dx}{dy} \cdot y -4x -y^6 = 0$
then $\frac{dx}{dy} - \frac{4}{y}x = y^5$
which gives $P(y)=\frac{-4}{y}$ and $f(y)=y^5$
and using the integrating factor I find the solution to be $\frac{x}{y^4} = \frac{y^2}{2}+C$
but the answer key has $x=2y^6+cy^4,(0, \infty)$

Questions:

1. When do you solve an ODE for the independent variable $x$ instead of the independent variable $y$? I guess normally formulas are written in terms of $y(x)=...$ because $x$ is what can be controlled to get the desired $y$?
2. Does the answer key have a typo? Shoudln't it be $\frac{y^6}{2}$ not $2y^6$?
3. Why is the interval $(0, \infty)$ instead of $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Comment: You seem to have misplaced a $dy$. I am not sure if that is a typo or the source of your error.

Comment: @Arkamis fixed the typo

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did something wrong in between , as i am getting the answer given in your book.

Starting from your first mistake.

$\frac{dx}{dy} - \frac{4}{y}x = 4y^5$
$\implies  y^{-4}\frac{dx}{dy} - \frac{4}{y^5}x = 4y$

$\implies y^{-4}x = 2y^2 + c$